# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ultralytics'

Tags: python, package, streamlit, yolov5

Im trying to deploy a YOLOV5 model to streamlit, everything works fine when I run this Locally, however when deployed I get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: This app has encountered an error. The original error message is redacted to prevent data leaks. Full error details have been recorded in the logs (if you're on Streamlit Cloud, click on 'Manage app' in the lower right of your app).

Traceback:

File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 557, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "app.py", line 33, in <module>
    model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path=run_model_path)
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 339, in load
    model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 368, in _load_local
    model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/appuser/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/hubconf.py", line 83, in custom
    return _create(path, autoshape=autoshape, verbose=_verbose, device=device)
File "/home/appuser/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/hubconf.py", line 33, in _create
    from models.common import AutoShape, DetectMultiBackend
File "/home/appuser/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/models/common.py", line 28, in <module>
    from utils.dataloaders import exif_transpose, letterbox
File "/home/appuser/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/utils/dataloaders.py", line 31, in <module>
    from utils.augmentations import (Albumentations, augment_hsv, classify_albumentations, classify_transforms, copy_paste,
File "/home/appuser/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/utils/augmentations.py", line 15, in <module>
    from utils.general import LOGGER, check_version, colorstr, resample_segments, segment2box, xywhn2xyxy
File "/home/appuser/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/utils/general.py", line 38, in <module>
    from ultralytics.yolo.utils.checks import check_requirements
```

I run a check and can see that from my local run, it fetches this file from cache:

> Using cache found in C:\Users\PC/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master

Was wondering how I could sort this - would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include `requirements.txt` containing all your installed modules to the root path of your project.
Looking at the error meassage, I think you are importing `check_requirements` from a module in a directory called `utils`. In this case, `append` the relative path of the module you want to import to your working directory before you import.
Example:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('./ultralytics/yolo')

from utils.checks import check_requirements
```